# Bundle pre-compiled NodeJS modules as tarball

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

I've created a C++ Node addon module (childModule) for my own use, which my main, larger, application depends on (parentModule). I'm distributing mainModule for consumption via a private NPM repo (Sinopia) and so far this as worked well on Unixy OS's (Mac OSX, Linux).

My end goal is to distribute parentModule as `.tgz` file resulting from `npm pack` command.

Problems occur on Windows with present Sinopia approach however relating to compilation and so I'd like to distribute pre-compiled binaries on this platform.  Node-pre-gyp works, however requires that I post the binaries to a hosting service, AWS for instance.

As childModule rarely changes, what I'd prefer to do is distribute a `childModule-1.0.0.tgz` which includes the pre-compiled binaries (what would normally be downloaded from AWS as per node-pre-gyp's default settings).

The question is, is it possible to place these pre-compiled binaries in a location in the childModules folder structure such that node-pre-gyp won't try to download them from the internet and instead just use the local copies?

If there doesn't exist such a way already, my approach will be to manually extract the `.node` file from the `tgz` file that node-pre-gyp creates, but wanted to see if anyone has already solved this problem.

Much thanks in advance!